Pi using Newton's approximation
Instead of taking the angle that the revolving line makes with the x-axis to be 60 degrees, if we take it to be 75 degrees, it should converge faster using the expansion for (1 - x^2)^0.5. But, when I do this, I get a value of pi that is far from the actual value. Can someone please help me? I do know MathJax and I know that I should include my own attempt, but am too tired after trying for a long time. Please don't delete my question.

You really haven't included enough here for a question, which is a shame because this might be quite interesting. I'm slightly having to guess at what you're asking, but if the approximation you're talking about is this one https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Newton%27s_Formula_for_Pi , then you'll notice it uses an expansion of $\sqrt{1-x}$, not $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ (which is what you have in your question).

Could you edit in an explanation of what a revolving line has to do with a Newtonian approximation of $\pi$? If it's a lot to type but there's a link to a discussion of it online, the link would help.

The revolving line doesn't really have anything to do with it. Its just the way how I learnt about an angle. So basically, when we draw an angle of 75 degrees in the unit circle and integrate, it divides into a sector and a triangle. The area of the sector can be found and it uses pi which is the main part of this method.

The equation of a circle in the plane is $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, from which we get $y = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$

@AkshajMishra that's a semicircle centred at $O$. The derivation in the link I shared (and elsewhere) involves a semicircle of radius $\frac12$ centred at $\left(\frac12,0\right)$, which has equation $y=\sqrt{x-x^2}=\sqrt{x}\cdot \sqrt{1-x}$. If you're using a different derivation can you share it (or a link)?

@ChrisLewis Check out veritasium's video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMlf1ELvRzc

Can we somehow take the limit as $\cos\theta$ approaches 0 for very quick convergence?

OK. So for the benefit of anyone who doesn't want to watch an 18 minute video, the calculation used is computing the area under the curve $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ from $x=0$ up to $x=\cos\theta$ (a sector plus a right-angled triangle) in two ways. Geometrically, the sector has area $\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2}$ and the triangle $\frac14 \sin{2\theta}$. The second way is use the binomial theorem to expand and integrate $\sqrt{1-x^2}$. In the video, $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$ is used. This makes the calculation fairly easy, because the substitution needed is $\cos{\theta}=\frac{1}{2}$. OP is suggesting..

...[cont] using $\theta=\frac{5\pi}{12}$. It's correct to say that the series thus generated would converge more quickly, since $\cos{\frac{5\pi}{12}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}<\frac12$. However, for manual calculation, substituting this value is much more complicated than substituting $\frac12$.

@AkshajMishra yes, but the value of $x$ you substitute into the series for the integral of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ gets more complicated. Also if you're approximating the area of smaller and smaller sectors, you have to multiply the approximation (and the error) by larger and larger numbers. There might be an optimal angle to use.

But if we can get a decent approximation from $(1+x)^n = 1 + nx$ then it doesn't really matter what the value of x is.

Can you tell me how we can go about finding the limit or a very fast converging series for it?

$\theta=81\deg$ seems to work pretty well.
